# Can this python code be expressed with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I find the following perfectly readable, but was wondering if their was a more pythonesque manner to accomplish it (perhaps a list comprehension)?

```
import re
cgi_keys = [ '_None___total', '_George___total', 'Greg__total', '_Geoff___total', '_Gillian_total' ]
pattern = re.compile(r"_(.+)___(.+)")
totals = []
for key in cgi_keys:
    m = pattern.match(key)
    if m:
        totals.append(m.groups())
totals
```

Which would display:

```
[('None', 'total'), ('George', 'total'), ('Geoff', 'total')]
```

But I was hoping I could figure out a way to get the above using a construct such as:

```
[key for key in cgi_keys if pattern.match(key)]
```

displaying the strings in a less useful form:

```
['_None___total', '_George___total', '_Geoff___total']
```

Is this worth trying to achieve breaking the filtered strings into tuples, or lists as a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could use:

```
totals = (pattern.match(key) for key in cgi_keys)
totals = [match.groups() for match in totals if match]
```

Which is shorter but still efficient because the first affectation is a generator whose values won't be evaluated until the second statement.

Also, you could use:

```
totals = [match.groups for match in filter(None, map(pattern.match, cgi_keys))]
```

As `map()` gives back a generator. You'd have to use [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) in Python 2 instead. Same goes for `ifilter`.

Note that if `cgi_keys` is really small, you may also use `map` in Python 2 as the extra-work done by iterating twice would likely be unnoticeable anyway.

Comment: Another formulation using nested list comprehensions: `[match.groups() for match in [pattern.match(key) for key in cgi_keys] if match]`

Comment: @chucksmash Yep, that's actually how I tried it in iPython but I wouldn't advise anyone to use that notation in production code. It doesn't change the code efficiency but hurts readability a lot. Some people even call that "uncomprehension lists".

Comment: Good point! I'm a sucker for "Is there a way?" type questions. It's all too easy to go happily along, never stopping to ask the more important question, "But should we?"

Comment: The `map` version doesn't filter out the `None` results from `pattern.match`, and so it breaks with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`.

Comment: @lvl Indeed i forgot adding in the `filter()`/`ifilter` calls.

Answer (score 2):

That can't be directly written as a (single) list comprehension without calling `pattern.match(key)` twice for each element - ie,

```
[pattern.match(key) for key in cgi_keys if pattern.match(key)]
```

However, you could move things around a bit by using a generator to skip over the `None` elements:

```
def skip_none(iter):
    return (i for i in iter if i is not None)

totals = skip_none(pattern.match(key) for key in cgi_keys)
```

Comment: Actually @unutbu just showed it could be done, but this comes at the price of extra-work and does not really help in understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex, and get list of lists rather than tuples.

```
[[v for v in cgi.split('_') if v] for cgi in cgi_keys]
```

Results in:

```
[['None', 'total'], ['George', 'total'], ['Greg', 'total'], ['Geoff', 'total'], ['Gillian', 'total']]
```

But if you need tuples:

```
[tuple([v for v in cgi.split('_') if v]) for cgi in cgi_keys]
```

Comment: I should have added a test case where a name can have an underscore in it, as in `"_George_Costanza___total_flake"` -> `['George_Costanza', 'total_flake']`, otherwise `split()` would have been my first choice.

Comment: @Jamie Ha! Love the George_Castanza total flake! Even though I think you're better off with `regex`, your test case can be addressed with `[[v[1:] if v[0] is '_' else v for v in cgi.split('__')] for cgi in cgi_keys]`.